# how to get the records from the user table on the basis of the decreasing number of matching records using active record codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am having two tables one is the user answers in which users answers some questions about himself

```
user_id   question_id  answer_id
1             2            3
1             4            2
1             2            1
1             2            3
1             4            1
2             2            3
2             4            2
2             2            1
2             2            3
2             4            1
```

the other one is the prefernce table in which the user answers about his partner

```
 user_id    question_id    answer_id
    1             2             3
    1             4             2
    1             2             1
```

what i need to do is first i have to take question_id and answer_id for a particular user from the second table and match the question_id and answer_id 
to the first table and we need to fetch the user detail from the third table on the basis of decreasing number of answer matched for that user to the other.

Comment: post your sql statements and i'll convert it for you - but i'm not gonna write an entire code for you ;)

Comment: The "second table" is just the first rows of the first, no?